# Why is this inner product sensible?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I'm trying to understand this statement given by Halmos:

[image]

Why does the inner product takes on all possible numerical values? I'm trying to extract this result seeing the cosines formula:

$$\cos(x,y)=\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{||x||\cdot||y||}$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: $\langle\lambda e, e\rangle = \lambda \langle e,e\rangle = \lambda$, unless I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: Do you mean to ask, *given* the cosine formula, show that $\langle x, y\rangle$ takes on all possible values? As @MarcinŁoś points out, it's easy to see from the more algebraic formula for an inner product of vectors represented by tuples in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Putting $x,y$ inside of cosine makes no sense at all. The quantity on the cosine is the angle between x and y.

Comment: @rschwieb no, my notation is not the same as Halmos $\cos(x,y)$ is the cosines between the vectors $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @MarcinŁoś I don't understand what you meant, the cosines is either +1 or -1 not the inner product.

Comment: I didn't say it had anything to do with Halmos's notation, only that $x,y$ is very strange notation for an angle between x and y. If you really want to denote it that way, it's fine, just a little surprising. I'll interpret it the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the book (*Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces*).

He's talking about why the inner product is a better representaion of the properties of two vectors than the angle between them. In the preceeding paragraphs he describes an inner product in $R^2$, where the angle can range from 0 to $2\pi$.

When you look at $R^1$ then the angle can only be 0 or $\pi$ while the inner product can be any value. So he says that the inner product shows greater sensitivity.

Hope the explanation helps, I'm not sure what conclusion I can draw from Halmos's statement.  If it gives you any deep insight into the universe please share it with us.

Comment: yes, but why is this statement true in $\mathbb R^2$? thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user42912. Which statement ? That the angle between two vectors takes a range of values 0 to 2$\pi$ is the statement he makes about $R^2$, which is clealry true. In the immediately preceding paragraph he notes potential confusion in notation between (x, y) as the inner product (in all dimensions) and (x, y) as an ordered pair in $R^2$. Has he succeeded in confusing you in this paragraph you're showing, because here (x,y) is refering to the inner product of two vectors x and y in $R^1$ ?

Comment: I think I understand now, thank you!

Comment: @user42912. Halmos can be a difficult read. If you find this challenging, try *Naive Set Theory*: despite the title this is an interesting journey through ZFC axiomatic set theory.

Comment: yes, I have this book, I've already read some pages, I will read the whole book next month definitely, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Enjoy it: I'm now about 1 year into it (on and off) and more or less understanding most of it.